# Use Pandas to write to excel sheets in specified order

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-excel

At the end of Pandas `.to_excel` [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) it shows how to write sheets in order:

```
>>> writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
>>> df1.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
>>> df2.to_excel(writer,'Sheet2')
>>> writer.save()
```

Is there a way for me to write to `sheet2` first, then `sheet1`, in my python program. However, I still need the `sheet1` to appear *before* `sheet2` in the final excel file?

Comment: So, you are asking for a way to insert a sheet at a specific index?

Comment: @kalyan - that's exactly right.

Comment: could you give a logical reason of why sheet2 can't be the firse worksheet and sheet1 can't be the second worksheet?

Comment: if the only logic is based on the number at the end, i mean 1 for sheet 1 and 2 for sheet2, you can first write all the data, and just modify the sheet names

Comment: Yes, for example I have 50 sheets with raw data and 1 sheet with summary. I need the summary sheet to be at the front. But content of the summary sheet isn't known until I go over creating the 50 sheets, which I want to create along the way since going over each sheet / content is expensive.

Comment: As a workaround for this specific issue, you could save each of your 50 sheets into a list of 50 mini dataframes, then write your summary to excel, and then write each of the 50 mini dataframes to its own sheet after.

Answer (score 4):

As [jmcnamara](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21118823/possible-to-alter-worksheet-order-in-xlsxwriter) wrote, it's not advisable to change the order of sheets because of Excel's internal structure, but you can change which sheet is active when the Excel file opens using `activate()`:

```
>>> writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
>>> df1.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
>>> df2.to_excel(writer,'Summary')
>>> writer.sheets['Summary'].activate()
>>> writer.save()
```

When you open the Excel file, the sheet called "Summary" will be displayed, although "Sheet1" will still be the first sheet.

Comment: helps but doesn't solve my core problem, in which I need Sheet1 to be at the front...

Answer (score -1):

Create a dictionary saving the sheets as values and sheet names as keys. Then select the order in which to write the sheets by creating a list of keys in the order desired.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
sheet_dict = {}
sheet_dict.update({'Sheet1': df1})
sheet_dict.update({'Summary': df2})
for key in ['Summary', 'Sheet1']:
   sheet_dict[key].to_excel(writer, key)
writer.save()
```

Comment: If you read my questions carefully, I cannot write `Summary` sheet before writing `Sheet1`