# xlsxwritter: add worksheet to the beginning of a multi-sheet workbook without affecting internal references

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Heads up, this is my 3rd day using python...

I'm working on an automated script to combine a bunch of excel workbooks.

While I've had no problem adding the data from a workbook containing a single worksheet to the end of a multi-sheet sheet book, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21118823/possible-to-alter-worksheet-order-in-xlsxwriter/21124112#21124112) 
indicates that attempting to add a worksheet to the beginning of the workbook would screw up the internally referenced data. As my starting workbook contains 4 worksheets that have interlinked equations, this has me worried.

According to [this web page](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues/317) there is no xlswritter method to do this because it 'It can be worked around in Python without any modification to the module', however, I'm not clear about how to implement the work around, so any help would be appreciated.

**How can I best go about moving worksheets around within a workbook while maintaining inter-sheet references?**